# Linq to DataSet?

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

I created a datatable with two column and four rows. I am trying to retrieve information from the row by linq based on the information I provide in the query statement for one column, but I get nothing in console.write statement.

```
    var super =
        from lang in JapanesePhrases.AsEnumerable()
        where lang.Field<string>("Meaning") == "Song of Truth"
        select lang.Field<string>("Phrase");

    foreach (string item in super)
    {
         Console.Write(item + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: are you expecting a .ToList at the end of your Select.. lang.Field<string> is a Generic looks like your linq statement is incorrect..

Comment: I bet you could improve that title if you liked: what _about_ Linq to DataSet?

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr: this is C#. Is `super` reserved in C#?

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr super is not a reserved word in c#

Comment: @DJKRAZE no I not expecting a list can you point out where I went wrong

Comment: if you get nothing in console output, means your collection is empty. check your query. not really clear what does DataSet matter here...

Comment: If nothing is written to the console, that means your LINQ query doesn't return any results. You should show a little bit more about your code: how do you construct the JapanesePhrases DataTable (assuming that _is_ the DataTable) for instance...

Comment: The DataTable and the added rows are fine the problem it with the linq statement, I am going wrong somewhere just got to figure out where.

Comment: Yes, that is probably so. But to tell you _what_ might be wrong with your LINQ query, we need to know a bit more about the DataTable. Are you for instance using the correct column names? Also, try to split your query into multiple parts: first save the where part in a temporary variable, and then do the select on that temp. This will make it a bit easier to debug (to see if the result set contains any elements after the where clause before you do the select etc.).

Comment: @ DaNet && John Saunders - oops sorry about that, wrong OO language

Comment: Also, you can try to skip the where part of your query, see what result you get if you only do ´from lang in JapanesePhrases.AsEnumerable() select lang.Field<string>("Phrase");´.

Comment: @DaNet: and what _was_ the answer? It is quite polite when you ask a question and find the answer yourself, to post the solution. There might be others who look for the same answer one day, and "Found the answer!" won't help them very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried now this code:

```
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Meaning");
    table.Columns.Add("Phrase");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row["Meaning"] = "Meaning"+i;
        row["Phrase"] = "Phrase"+i;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    var super = from lang in table.AsEnumerable()
                where lang.Field<string>("Meaning") == "Meaning1" 
                select lang.Field<string>("Phrase");

    foreach (string item in super)
    {
        Console.Write(item + "\n");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

running seamlessly.

i should check data in datatable.

Comment: Again the datatable is fine the only difference is that I have 4 rows of data                                                   DataRow rows = table.NewRow();
rows["Phrase"] = "data";                       
rows["Meaning"] = "data";
table.Rows.Add(rows);                                                                               DataRow rows = table.NewRow();
rows["Phrase"] = "data";
rows["Meaning"] = "data";
table.Rows.Add(rows);

Comment: you should  take a look super use debug. Is set super ?